# Store password to a corresponding email address in a table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on website project there I have got a problem when I am trying to save the password corresponding to the email using a stored procedure.

I have tried it using stored procedure like that

```
USE [eventmania]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_PasswordSet]    Script Date: 07/30/2013     17:11:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PasswordSet] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Password nvarchar(50)='',
    @Email nvarchar(50)=''
    --@id int=default
AS
BEGIN
        if exists(select Email from dbo.Complete_Registeration where Email=@Email)
    begin
    insert into dbo.Complete_Registeration([password]) values(@Password)
    end
END
```

Comment: Side note - storing passwords is not very good idea. Store hash of password instead

Comment: How to use hash of password?

Comment: [How to Hash Passwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You want `UPDATE` not `INSERT` e.g.

```
UPDATE dbo.Complete_Registration
SET password = @Password
WHERE email = @Email
```

Also, I hope you aren't storing plain-text passwords...

Answer (score 0):

The row already exists, you want to use an `UPDATE` statement instead.

Try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Complete_Registeration SET [password] = @Password WHERE Email = @Email
```

Comment: The `EXISTS` check is an unnecessary overhead here.